# Node.js - constructor on same line as require

Tags: node.js, constructor, module

Why does this seem to work (variable is received on other end of constructor):

```
var lib = require('lib');
lib('abc');
```

While at the same time, this seems to yield different results:

```
var lib = require('lib')('abc');
```

I would think they would do the same thing, but I obviously have something wrong.

Comment: Are you missing `new`?

Comment: Eh, I was trying to reproduce a similar functionality to `var koa = require('koa');`
`var app = koa();` This doesn't seem to need `new`.

Comment: Obviously `lib` will end up being different things. Define "different results".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man - I hit a new low with this question. Thanks to @Dave Network who tipped me off.

My `constructor` for `lib` was not returning itself (`module.exports`) after completion. After fixing this, the results ended up the same.

Answer (score 0):

These mean entirely different things, though it's possible that the module in question is written in such a way that they happen to do the same thing.

```
var lib = require('lib');
lib('abc');
```

This says "call the function `require`, and assign its return value to the variable `lib`". Presumably, it's returning a function, because we then immediately call that function.

```
var lib = require('lib')('abc');
```

This says "call the function `require`, which returns a function, then call that function, and assign that second function's return value to the variable `lib`." That second function might return anything, a number,a string, etc. But not necessarily a function (though it might return that as well).

So after the first choice, we know that `lib` is a function. After the second choice, we don't.